# Have you heard about zippykid?

Tags: wordpress

Have you heard about zippykid ?
I see one of the site is having the following CDN urls in wordpress
uegbwbxgk1hqwla1-zippykid.netdna-ssl.com

How can I disable this CDN and use the default wordpress urls ?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not asking about a programming-related problem; Stack Overflow is not a discussion forum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My name is Roberto Villarreal and I am a part of the Pressable team (formerly known as ZippyKid).

These CDN URLs are automatically put into place for customers through a mu-plugin called wp-stack-cdn.php

This file is inside /wp-content/mu-plugins/ alongside others that are a part of Pressable services.

If you want to get rid of these CDN URLs, you should remove the wp-stack-cdn.php plugin and that will take care of it.

I would advise, however, that if you are a moving a site away from the service, that you follow this knowledge base article:

http://kb.pressable.com/pressable-tutorials/move-site-pressable/

This will help ensure you do not run into any other conflicts or issues with plugins that we have in place for use on our services.

Hope this helps!